# How can I turn off the "Numbers" application?

Tags: ms-office, numbers, csv

"Numbers" is the Mac OS counterpart to Excel.  When you extract data from the Web, you can often export it into the .csv format, which is just a primitive version of Excel limited to a single worksheet.  It is very easy to "save as" a .csv file into an .xls file.

But, with Mac OS, when you export data into a .csv file, it actually exports it to Numbers. The interface is quite different. Is there a way to turn off Numbers so it does not automatically capture .csv data exports?

Comment: What do you mean by capture? How do you export the data, from where?

Comment: The CSV file format is the same as neither the Numbers file format nor any other Excel file formats. You can perfectly open the CSV formatted files even using a simple text editor such as TextEdit on macOS (or Notepad on Windows). It just appears that the default program to open CSV files on your Mac is Numbers as is the case by default, unless changed by the users, on many other Mac computers. You can change the default program associated with the CSV files on your Mac by following the directions @ErniePC12 provides below.

Comment: A CSV file is **not** a **primitive** form of Excel. The CSV file is a method of transferring data between programs in a controlled fashion, check out the standards for CSV files.

Answer (score 6):

To really address your question, you can uninstall the application or you can just change it so that all .csv files are opened in your application of choice.

Just right-click on a file that uses the file type you'd like to change the default for. For example, one with a .csv extension.

- Click on Get Info in the pop-up.
- Click Open With if the section isn't already expanded.
- Click the drop-down menu.
- Click the app you want to use.
- Click Change All...
- Click Continue when the Finder asks you if you're sure

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on current Macs. Your solution is specific to a single, specific .csv file.

Comment: Did you click the "Change All" button? That will set all files of that type to open in the application that is selected in the popup menu.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add on to the answer provided by ErniePC12.  Doing a right-click did not work for me.  Instead I went to File -> Open With.  And, everything worked out ok.

Comment: That does a different thing - the get info changes it for all .csv now onwards whilst yours just does the current file

Comment: Somehow, right clicking did not get me there.